# Return a List<List<E>> in Java

Tags: java, list, return-type

i have to write a method that return the same type as in title.
But as you all know, List is an interface, and therefore has no instance.
In my code, i use  'ArrayList<ArrayList>listList'  to store the information to return.
But as i try to return listList, such Error occurs

```
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ArrayList<E>> to List<List<E>>
```

So how can i return it?
I've tried to declare

```
            List<ArrayList<E>>listList// still cant return
    List<List<E>>listList//this cant be declared
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is because java generics are **invariant**. If you want to use the type **List<ArrayList<E>>** in your code you must use as return type **List<? extends List<E>>**

Comment: I mean, you can just use `List<List<E>>`.  You just have to use `ArrayList<List<E>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value may look just like this:

```java
public static <E> List<List<E>> foo() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
// or immutable empty list
public static <E> List<List<E>> foo() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

> *I use 'ArrayListlistList' to store the information to return*
> The result to return can and should be declared as `List<List<E>>` but it has to be initialized properly with the list implementation:

```java
public static <E> List<List<E>> bar(E item) {
    List<List<E>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new ArrayList<>());
    result.get(0).add(item);
    return result;
}

public static <E> List<List<E>> bar1(E item) {
    List<List<E>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(Arrays.asList(item));
    return result;
}
```

Starting from Java 9, `List.of` may be used (an immutable `List` implementation is returned):

```java
public static <E> List<List<E>> bar2(E item) {
    return List.of(
        List.of(item)
    );
}
```